# Ways of finding associations in time series

Tags: time-series, data-mining

I am trying to develop a logic to identify association between different time series for association mining. I have a lot of series and need to find whether or not the association exists. I figured two ways to do this:

1. Constructive: try to find relation in given two series.
2. Destructive: try to prove that relation does not exist.

Are there any existing mathematical parameters to identify such relations? if not, any suggestions?

Comment: Just curious - is this financial data or something else?

Comment: Ya. These are sales time series.

Comment: Correlations, eh?

Comment: If you want to know whether the sales of 2 different items we related, the first place to start would be to calculate the % change in sales for each item, and then measure their correlation.  Or perhaps you are asking something more subtle, like how to decide whether a correlation is statistically significant?

Comment: Yes I am looking for the second thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ordinary cross-correlation coefficient between two time series is possibly  meaningless due to auto-correlation in either of the series see http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/dbs202/cat/stats/corr.html for a refresher about the assumptions of joint bivariate normality assumption required to test the cross-correlation  or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udny_Yule for one of the earlier references of Spurious Correlation. That being the case one can pre-whiten using the ARIMA model for the "x series" and compute cross-correlations of the suitably filtered series. This is analogous to pulling out the within relationship in order to identify the among relationship. This leads to a Transfer Function which may or may not include empirically identified Pulses, Level Shifts , Local Time Trends and/or Seasonal Pulses to render the model's error process Gaussian. Given this and ( some more ) one may then be able to test the incremental value of "x" in describing "y's behavior". Books from authors like Wei or G.E.P.Box or Hanssens might be useful to you to provide "reading support"

Comment: Excellent response sir... I understood till why Correlation is bad... but can you kindly explain what to do? I didn't quite get you..

Comment: If you post your two time series to the list, I wll try and explain what has to be done.

Comment: ok. It is http://mihirsathe.com/mihir/STI/STI/clothing_women/index.html this one and http://mihirsathe.com/mihir/STI/STI/jewelry/index.html this one

Comment: :mihsathe Is this daily data (5/7 days a week ) if so  starting when ?

Comment: Oh, this is the monthly data starting from Jan 1994 to May 2011

Comment: As told by you and referencing Makridakis book, I removed non stationarity with 1-shift and removed seasonal with 12 and 6 shifts. Now my almost all autocorrelations are well below     +-1.96/root(n) for 1-20 degrees of freedoms. Is it safe to take cross-correlations now?

Comment: :mihsathe . Yes it is safe. That is approximately what is shown in my first image in my second answer.

Answer (score 1):

you asked me to explain what has to be done .

[image: enter code here] Initially one plots the data ! the data had a level shift which presents itself as two separate clusters[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYIVb.jpg) and the develops an ARIMA model for clothes which is used to prewhiten the observed X and Y . the two filtered series x and y are then examined via cross-correlation in[image]. Exanination of the cross-correlations suggests an initial model[image] . This model is then evaluated and improved to a final model containing empirically identified deterministic series ( level shifys, pulses )[image] with [image] yielding [image] and [image]